# Django making a user comment on a post where the user is automatically made the author

Tags: python, django

Hello im trying to make a django application where when a post is made the someone who is logged in can comment on the post but it will automatically insert their name/account rather then them having to put it. So all the user has to do is add body content.
forms.py
'''

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name','body',)
```

'''
views.py
'''

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.cleared.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'posts/post/list.html'



def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'posts/post/detail.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'new_comment': new_comment,'comment_form': comment_form})
```

'''
models.py
'''

```
from django_currentuser.db.models import CurrentUserField
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                    self).get_queryset()\
                         .filter(status='cleared')
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('cleared','Cleared'),('UnderReview','Being Reviewed'),('banned','Banned'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 300, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='forum_posts',null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='cleared')
    objects = models.Manager()
    cleared = PublishedManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering =('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='comments',null=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

'''
urls.py
'''

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
```

'''
With the current code I get this error when I go to the post_detail page
"no such column: posts_comment.name_id"

***EDIT*
Incase anyone is having trouble with redirect  I found some code that works**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from mysite.blog.models import Post

def comment_posted( request ):
    if request.GET['c']:
        comment_id, post_id  = request.GET['c'].split( ':' )
        post = Post.objects.get( pk=post_id )

        if post:
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )

    return HttpResponseRedirect( "/" )
```

Now the code looks like this on my project
"""

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post = post
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user
            comment_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'posts/post/detail.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form})
```

"""
When someone adds a comment it basically refreshes the page and displays the new comment as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can patch this to the object, just like you did this for the `.post`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post = post
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user
            new_comment_form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'posts/post/detail.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: I followed your exact instructions but im still getting :                                                         "no such column: posts_comment.name_id" as an error when I try to load the page I have the user model in a different app idk if that is what is causing it

Comment: @JoeG: ah, it looks like you also forgot to migrate the database (`makemigrations` and `migrate`).

Comment: I did the migrations but it seems I had to delete all the previous migrations and the database and it did seem to work however now when I try to post I get an error saying ("new_comment_form" is not defined) btw thank you so much for your help so far ive been stuck on this for a couple of hours. When I change the last (new_comment_form) to comment_form.save() I get a no reverse match.

Comment: @JoeG: ah, but the *`'name-of-some-view'`* should be replaced to the *name* of a view to which it should redirect. In case of a succesful POST, you should make a redirect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying thank you for your patience and help im going to keep experimenting with proper redirect urls